# Средства мониторинга выделения памяти для Java классов

Tags: java

Есть ли какие то способы для определения объемов выделения памяти для каждого класса в программе?

Comment: [jol](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)

Comment: я краем глаза глянул, а есть что-нибудь с визуализацией и так что бы я мог конкретно по классам моего проекта просмотреть?

Answer (score 2):

Самый простой вариант - это снимать heap-dump и анализировать его в Eclipse MAT (Memory Analyzer Tooling). Как это делается - можно подсмотреть в [статье](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/08/create-and-understand-java-heapdumps-act-4/). А уже в самом mat очень много всевозможных инструментов - как для анализа своего кода, так и для анализа взаимодействия со сторонними библиотеками.

UPD: В вашем случае нужно найти необходимый класс. А далее - все что угодно. Количество инстансов, где порождаются, объемы и тд.